# Camera preview in UIView is not showing full

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, camera, avcapturedevice

I have an `UIView` inside an `UIViewController`, using the below code for showing camera in preview mode. The camera preview is shown but its not the same height of `UIView`.
The `UIView` has constraints Leading Space to superview - 40, Trailing space to superview - 40, Align Centre X to superview, bottom space to superview - 40, top space to superview - 40.

Could you please help me fix the issue.

Thanks.

```
- (void)startCameraPreview {

    AVCaptureDevice* camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (camera == nil) {
        return;
    }

    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:camera error:nil];
    [captureSession addInput:newVideoInput];

    captureLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
    captureLayer.frame = captureView.bounds;
    [captureLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [captureView.layer addSublayer:captureLayer];

    UIView *view = [self captureView];
    CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
    [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
    [captureLayer setFrame:bounds];

    // Start the session. This is done asychronously since -startRunning doesn't return until the session is running.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [captureSession startRunning];
    });

}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem??